# Cordova cannot find gradle

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

My Cordova won't find the Gradle. I searched all other posts about this problem but they all found the gradle somewhere in their tools folder but I can't find it.

Cordova and Android SDK are updated to latest. And I have my PATH variables in **~/.profile**

```
$ cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/jarno/0__software/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

**Android SDK tools directory (short):**

```
- bin
- lib
- proguard
- support
```

**Android SDK tools directory (long):**

```
Android/Sdk/tools$ tree -d



├── bin
├── lib
│   ├── monitor-x86
│   │   ├── configuration
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.update
│   │   ├── features
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_25.4.0.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.e4.rcp_1.1.2.v20130130-191718-91FUvGP7GIX2Kgz-z-gvjMvXV1NS
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.emf.common_2.8.0.v20130125-0546
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.8.3.v20130125-0546
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-8297FndFWmE7h7Bpz-vcqkxyKz0
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-7A6FEcDiVOTg2RYDuZuFz-L2z00w
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-785EoBqNKNZz-DW7sUc8hFwz00wd
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui_2.2.0.v20121212-204731-62DG9JXTlTj-UXcQ2y3NLn6U4Z3H
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.help_1.4.1.v20120912-144938-8R7xFOXFLWUl7PpNBh_HIGkb4
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.rcp_4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h
│   │   │       └── META-INF
│   │   ├── p2
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core
│   │   │   │   └── cache
│   │   │   │       └── binary
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine
│   │   │       └── profileRegistry
│   │   │           └── DefaultProfile.profile
│   │   ├── plugins
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.101.v20130108-163257
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200
│   │   │   │   ├── cheatsheets
│   │   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   │   └── topiclabel
│   │   │   │   ├── intro
│   │   │   │   │   └── css
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524
│   │   │       ├── icons
│   │   │       │   └── full
│   │   │       │       ├── elcl16
│   │   │       │       └── obj16
│   │   │       ├── META-INF
│   │   │       └── themes
│   │   │           ├── circles
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── ctool
│   │   │           │   │   │   └── obj48
│   │   │           │   │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │           │   │   ├── rootpage
│   │   │           │   │   └── standby
│   │   │           │   ├── html
│   │   │           │   └── swt
│   │   │           ├── purpleMesh
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── ctool
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── dtool
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── etool
│   │   │           │   │   │   └── obj48
│   │   │           │   │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │           │   │   ├── root
│   │   │           │   │   └── swt
│   │   │           │   ├── html
│   │   │           │   └── swt
│   │   │           ├── shared
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   └── icons
│   │   │           │   │       └── ctool
│   │   │           │   └── html
│   │   │           └── slate
│   │   │               ├── graphics
│   │   │               │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │               │   ├── icons
│   │   │               │   │   └── ctool
│   │   │               │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │               │   ├── rootpage
│   │   │               │   └── standby
│   │   │               ├── html
│   │   │               └── swt
│   │   └── readme
│   ├── monitor-x86_64
│   │   ├── configuration
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.update
│   │   ├── features
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_25.4.0.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature_25.2.2.3859397
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.e4.rcp_1.1.2.v20130130-191718-91FUvGP7GIX2Kgz-z-gvjMvXV1NS
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.emf.common_2.8.0.v20130125-0546
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.8.3.v20130125-0546
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-8297FndFWmE7h7Bpz-vcqkxyKz0
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-7A6FEcDiVOTg2RYDuZuFz-L2z00w
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature_1.1.0.v20121211-153934-785EoBqNKNZz-DW7sUc8hFwz00wd
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui_2.2.0.v20121212-204731-62DG9JXTlTj-UXcQ2y3NLn6U4Z3H
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.help_1.4.1.v20120912-144938-8R7xFOXFLWUl7PpNBh_HIGkb4
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.rcp_4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h
│   │   │       └── META-INF
│   │   ├── p2
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core
│   │   │   │   └── cache
│   │   │   │       └── binary
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine
│   │   │       └── profileRegistry
│   │   │           └── DefaultProfile.profile
│   │   ├── plugins
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.101.v20130108-163257
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   ├── org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200
│   │   │   │   ├── cheatsheets
│   │   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   │   └── topiclabel
│   │   │   │   ├── intro
│   │   │   │   │   └── css
│   │   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │   └── org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524
│   │   │       ├── icons
│   │   │       │   └── full
│   │   │       │       ├── elcl16
│   │   │       │       └── obj16
│   │   │       ├── META-INF
│   │   │       └── themes
│   │   │           ├── circles
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── ctool
│   │   │           │   │   │   └── obj48
│   │   │           │   │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │           │   │   ├── rootpage
│   │   │           │   │   └── standby
│   │   │           │   ├── html
│   │   │           │   └── swt
│   │   │           ├── purpleMesh
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   ├── icons
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── ctool
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── dtool
│   │   │           │   │   │   ├── etool
│   │   │           │   │   │   └── obj48
│   │   │           │   │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │           │   │   ├── root
│   │   │           │   │   └── swt
│   │   │           │   ├── html
│   │   │           │   └── swt
│   │   │           ├── shared
│   │   │           │   ├── graphics
│   │   │           │   │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │           │   │   └── icons
│   │   │           │   │       └── ctool
│   │   │           │   └── html
│   │   │           └── slate
│   │   │               ├── graphics
│   │   │               │   ├── contentpage
│   │   │               │   ├── icons
│   │   │               │   │   └── ctool
│   │   │               │   ├── launchbar
│   │   │               │   ├── rootpage
│   │   │               │   └── standby
│   │   │               ├── html
│   │   │               └── swt
│   │   └── readme
│   ├── x86
│   └── x86_64
├── proguard
│   ├── ant
│   ├── bin
│   ├── docs
│   │   └── manual
│   │       └── retrace
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── annotations
│   │   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       └── proguard
│   │   │           └── annotation
│   │   ├── ant
│   │   └── dictionaries
│   └── lib
└── support
```

Comment: I know it's an old issue but I have the same problem.